# How to update a submodule in git to the HEAD commit in that external repo

Tags: git, version-control, external, git-submodules

I had problems finding the answer to this so I am posting it for posterity.

The situation is, you have a git repo with a submodule (similar to an svn external).  You want to update that reference to point to a different commit in the external repository.  You might think 'git submodule sync' or 'git submodule update' would do that - you'd be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps are:

- cd to the actual directory the submodule is in.
- run 'git pull origin' or whatever you want to do to set it to a new commit.
- cd out of that directory (presumably to the repository root) and run "git status" - you will see that the directory is changed.  If you do a diff you will see something like this:

```
diff --git a/default/bin/hdvcs b/default/bin/hdvcs
index bbd3f56..7c9394c 160000
--- a/default/bin/hdvcs
+++ b/default/bin/hdvcs
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit bbd3f56898054e533e81b52b90b94155841b40a8
+Subproject commit 7c9394c8520e41a704e6658360064758b20a3dfc
```

- commit this change.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update all your git submodules to HEAD of the remote repo just type

> git submodule foreach git pull origin master